# How to prove $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{xy}{x^4+y^4}$ does not exist

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{xy}{x^4+y^4}$$

Anyone can teach me how to solve this question? I have tried so many times but still unable to solve it.

Comment: Work out what happens as $x\to0$ with $y$ held fixed at zero. Then work out what happens as you approach the origin along the curve $y=x^4$. Then write up what you have found, and post it as an answer.

Comment: Try to choose a suitable path depending on some variable constant.

Comment: Well the fact that the expression has transposable variables (i.e. $f(x,y) \equiv f(y,x)$) means that you just need to find $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x,x)$, or more precisely: $$\lim_{x\to 0}{2x^{-2}}$$ I think

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{xy}{x^4+y^4}$ exits then in some deleted nbd of $(0,0)$ the function $f:\Bbb R^2-\{(0,0)\}\rightarrow \Bbb R,f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^4+y^4}$ will be bounded . But notice that on the set $S:=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2-\{(0,0)\}: x=y\}$ the function $f$ is of the form $\frac{x^2}{2x^4}=\frac{1}{2x^2}$ i.e. in every deleted nbd of $(0,0)$ the function is unbounded.

$lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} f(x,y)=l\implies$ for $\epsilon=1$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $0<x^2+y^2<\delta\implies |f(x,y)-l|<1\implies l-1<f(x,y)<l+1 , \forall (x,y)$ with $0<x^2+y^2<\delta$ i.e. $f$ is bounded in a deleted nbd of $(0,0)$.